# how to use forEach function with operator()

Tags: c++, opencv, pixel

I'm trying to do an operation on every pixel of an image with the 'forEach' function of the cv::Mat class. but I get a memory exception error.

I have the source image (in HLS) with typedef HLSPixel of 3d-point of double.
I've made a class with operator() overloaded.

```cpp
typedef cv::Point3_<double> HLSPixel;

struct Quantize
{
    void operator()(HLSPixel& in, const int* position ) const 
    {
        if (in.y < 30)
        {
            in.y = 0;
        }
        else if(in.y > 225)
        {
            in.y = 255;
        }
        else
        {
            in.z /= 25;
            in.z *= 25;
        }
    }
};
void main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture vid("video.mp4")
    cv::Mat hls;
    cv::Mat bgr_frame;

    vid >> bgr_frame;

    cv::cvtColor(bgr_frame, hls, cv::COLOR_BGR2HLS);

    hls.forEach<HLSPixel, Quantize>(Quantize());//it crashes here.

}
```

I expect the image to be processed with the operator() but it just crashes :(.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: probably is simply: `hsv_frame.forEach<HLSPixel>(PianoQuantize());`, and `typedef cv::Point3_<uchar> HLSPixel;` as explained in the documentation

Comment: edited my question, OK now?

Comment: thank you Miki!  it's working now! how will i know what are the types in every color coding?

Comment: again, read the doc: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab ;). Usually CV_8UC3

Comment: you don't need to call an functor when passing to `forEach` `hls.forEach<HLSPixel, Quantize>(Quantize` `()` `)`